# Creating a hyperlink on a GridView column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with a column called, "Keys". How do I make it such that all the value in the column `Key's` have a hyperlink that calls another function (c#), and still retain the same name as before.

I should mention that the `GridView` has data set to it depending no user input, it isn't hard coded in to the website. Depending on what the user inputs, it runs an sql stored procedure, and updates the `GridView` accordingly.

An example of my Data Binding.

```
private void parseData(string command)
{
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            SqlCommand instruc = new SqlCommand(command, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet table = new DataSet();
            myDA.SelectCommand = instruc;
            myDA.Fill(table);
            dataTest.DataSource = table;
            dataTest.DataBind();
        }

}
```

GridView ASP Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataTest" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanging="gv_SelectedIndexChanging">
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the

> RowDataBoundEvent

In this event you create the linkbutton.

and

> SelectedIndexChangingEvent
>   In this event you can then call any C# functions you like.

Something like this should work:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanging="gv_SelectedIndexChanging"></asp:GridView>

    protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var gv = sender as GridView;
        var dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow;
        var value = dr["Keys"] as string;
        var lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.CommandName = "Select";
        lb.Command += Lb_Command;
        lb.Text = value;
    }
}

private void Lb_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        var lb = sender as LinkButton;
        var row = lb.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow; // can be parent depends lb.Parent.Parent...
    }
}

protected void gv_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    // event fired after Linkbutton click
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like that, but after the data is bound, it doesn't execute the gv_RowDataBound method, even if the GridView is subscribed to the event.

Comment: The OnRowDataBound event is called once when databind() is called. It doesn't run multiple times during page processing. On postback you have to call databind() again.

Comment: I've put a breakpoint in the OnRowDataBound event, and it doesn't halt my program when executed.

Comment: where do you create the gridview, can we see that, and in which event?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been specific, in the example above, "dataTest" is the name of my gridview. I also don't know where to code to create the grid view lies... I just dragged and dropped the gridview in from the designer.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work... It might help to subscribe to the event on the correct gridview...

Comment: I got the hyperlinks to work, however the linkbutton event isn't being fired on click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115526/discussion-between-legends-and-highmans).